# Is there any way to distribute windows phone app (xap file) for testers on multiple devices without uploading on windows store?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

For eg. we use https://testflightapp.com to distribute iOS app (also android now) and for Android directly send across the .apk file. But windows phone is not allowing installing the app directly using build .xap file.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible when the devices of the testers are registers as developer devices. This in turn means that your testers need to have a developer account. You as developer can register up to 5 devices as developer devices under your account, even if they don't belong to you. Other than that you cannot deploy an xap package onto a device.

When you upload an app to the Windows Phone you can mark this app as beta. This will lead to a reduced certification time and you can update your beta any time. Then you can provide up to 10000 E-Mail addresses of users that will test your app and only those will be able to download it. You can find more info on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)